# When, typically, do you use == equality on a reference typed variable in Java / C#?

Tags: c#, java

As a kind of follow up to the question titled "Difference Between Equals and ==": in what kind of situations would you find yourself testing for reference equality in Java / C#?

Answer (score 6):

Consolidating answers ...

> When, typically, do you use ==
>   equality on a reference typed variable
>   in Java / C#?

**1. To check for null:**

```
if (a == null) ...
```

**2. For efficiency when you are constructing an equals implementation:**

```
boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null)      return false;
    if (this == o)      return true;

    // Some people would prefer "if (!(o instanceof ClassName)) ..."
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())   return false;

    // Otherwise, cast o, leverage super.equals() when possible, and
    // compare each instance variable ...
```

**3. For efficiency when you are comparing enums or comparing objects of a class designed such that comparing object identity is equivalent to checking object equivalence (e.g. Class objects):**

```
enum Suit { DIAMONDS, HEARTS, CLUBS, SPADES }

class SomeCardGame {
    ...
    boolean static isATrumpCard(Card c) {
        return (c.getSuit() == TRUMP_SUIT);
    }
}
```

**4. When you really intend to check object identity, not object equivalence, e.g. a test case that wants to make sure a class isn't giving up a reference to an internal data structure instance.**

```
boolean iChoseNotToUseJUnitForSomeReasonTestCase() {
    final List<String> externalList = testObject.getCopyOfList();
    final List<String> instanceVariableValue =
        getInstanceVariableValueViaCleverReflectionTrickTo(testObject, "list");
    if (instanceVariableValue == externalList) {
      System.out.println("fail");
    } else {
      System.out.println("pass");
    }
}
```

Interestingly, for point #3, one article suggests using equals is *safer* than using .equals() because the compiler will complain if you attempt to compare to object references that are not of the same class (http://schneide.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/or-equals/).

Comment: "if (this == null) return null;" should be "if (o == null) return false;"

Answer (score 5):

For Java, most commonly to see if a reference is null:

```
 if (someReference == null) {
 //do something
 }
```

It is also pretty common with enums, but the most common place to use it that I've seen is in a properly implemented equals method. The first check will check for reference equality and only do the more expensive calculation if that returns false.

Comment: Well, you saved me the trouble of finishing my answer. ;) +1

Comment: Just as an addition, the reason it's common with enums is that there is only a fixed, limited set of enum instances.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's so fast and simple, `==` is routinely part of the `Equals()` function.  If two objects are `==`, then they're `Equals`, and you don't need any further processing.  For primitives in Java, `==` is your only option (I don't think that's true of C#, but am not sure).  I'll use `==` to test for null (although more frequently it's `!=`).  Other than that... Stick with `Equals()`.  It's rare and probably a sign of trouble to need `==` over `Equals`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it for quick equality checks.

For example if you are doing a compare with some very large objects that may take a while to iterate through, you can save time to see if they are referring to the same object first

```
Compare(LargeObj a, LargeObj b) {
if (a == b)
  return true;

// do other comparisons here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the == operator may be overloaded, which would mean that you can compare reference types for LOGICAL equality.

Any time the implementer of a class thought that it would be logical to compare equality, *you may do so using their methods*.

This being said, be careful when checking `if (a == b)` in C#.  This MAY be a reference equals, or it MAY be a logical comparison.

In order to keep the two cases distinct, it could be a good idea to use the two following methods, just to be clear:

```
object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)
a.Equals(b)
```

The first one is a reference comparison, and the second is usually a logical one.

here is a typical == overload, just for reference:

```
public static bool operator ==(RRWinRecord lhs, RRWinRecord rhs)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((object)lhs == null || (object)rhs == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return lhs.Wins == rhs.Wins &&
            lhs.Losses == rhs.Losses &&
            lhs.Draws == rhs.Draws &&
            lhs.OverallScore == rhs.OverallScore;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid == with objects that are normally defined with final static and then passed as members in classes that are serialized.

For example (before we had enums) I had a class defined that simulated the idea of an enumeration. Since the constructor was private and all allowed instances were defined as final statics I wrongly assumed that == was always safe to use on these objects.

For example (typing code without compiling, so excuse me if there are some issues with the code)

```
public class CarType implements Serializable {
  public final static CarType DODGE = new CarType("Dodge");
  public final static CarType JEEP = new CarType("JEEP");

  private final String mBrand;

  private CarType( String pBrand ) {
     mBrand = pBrand;
  }

  public boolean equals( Object pOther ) {
     ...
  }
}
```

The CarType instances were serialized when used in other objects... but after materialisation (on a different JVM instance) the == operation failed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use == when you "know" that "==" is equivalent to ".equals" (in Java).

By doing so, you can gain performance.

A simple example where you'll see this is in a .equals method.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // early short circuit test
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    // rest of equals method...
}
```

But in some algorithms, you have good knowledge of the objects you're working with, so you can rely on == for tests. Such as in containers, working with graphs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference (C#) is to always leave == to mean reference equality (referring to the same object).  If I need logical equivalence, I'll use Equals<T>.  If I follow this rule uniformly, then there's never any confusion.